# JQuery form submit multiple select, group selected values to csv array

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

For my website I am doing a movie search form. IT will do a get ( in order to have more or less friendly url ) with the fields selected by the user. I have a genre multiple select. My problem is that the form output looks like :

```
Movie/Search?rlow=5.0&rheigh=10.0&genre=1&genre=5&genre=2&sortby=DateAddedDesc
```

How can I group using jquery genre parameter into a csv string like :

```
Movie/Search?rlow=5.0&rheigh=10.0&genre=1,5,2&sortby=DateAddedDesc
```

Is this reliable method? Or I should rely on `form.submit()` method ?

Comment: Where is the code which makes your get request?

Answer (score 1):

Yes catch the submit event.

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
   genres = $("#target #select").val().join(",") //create Genres
   //Build link
   event.preventDefault(); //disable sending form
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `POST` instead of `GET`......